# Reading ASCII files

Tags: python

How to read ASCII file containing time series data in and how to plot the time series using Python. Example

2005-01-10 12:00:03. 132    25.12

2005-01-10 12:00:04. 231    28.23

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same format everywhere, you can just use datetime.strptime()

```
from datetime import datetime
time_series = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        time_data = " ".join(line.strip().split(' ')[0:2])
        time_series.append(datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S."))
```

Then, just plot using matplotlib